# syntax difference between ruby and python?

Tags: python, ruby

i wonder if there are tutorials that go through the syntax differences for ruby and python?

i have seen a comparison between ruby and php but not between ruby and python.

i have looked at both ruby and python but it would be very useful with this side-by-side comparison for deciding which one to choose.

thanks

Comment: Why is syntax the best way to pick a technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the link from ruby language site: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-python/

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonVsRuby.